# Problema sobre geração de wordlist em Python (2.7)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando escrever um script em python que pegue n palavras chave e um número como input. Esse número vai ser meu range máximo da string que vai ser escrita na wordlist.

1° Problema: Tem que ser feito o máximo de combinações possíveis entre essas strings do input, sem perder nenhuma combinação possível ou string no meio do caminho;

2º Problema: Se ultrapassar o range definido no input, a string não pode ser cortada, simplesmente a palavra que não encaixa no "espaço" predefinido fica de fora da string do processo em questão, mas as palavras que ficam de fora também precisam passar pelo processo de ter o máximo de combinações possíveis com todas as outras palavras.

Meu código possui umas saídas de tela porque estou debugando mas a ideia é que a saída no final vá para um arquivo texto.

Estou quase lá, mas as strings ainda saem com uma letra ou duas que não deveriam.

Meu código é o seguinte (python 2.7):

```
import sys
import itertools

maxi = sys.argv[1]

  if int(maxi) > 24:
    print ">>For secure, the max of range of string was setup as 24<<"
    print "Old value: " + maxi
    maxi = 24

maxi = int(maxi)

words = sys.argv[2:]
wn = len(words)
print words
print "Inserted Words: " + str(len(words))

cw = 0
cutd = 0
nwords = []
tmp = ""
for word in itertools.imap(''.join, itertools.permutations(words, r=wn)):
    if len(word) <= maxi:
        nwords.append(word)
        nwords = list(set(nwords))
        cw = cw+1
                #Permutations, slicing of the big ones
    else: 
        word = word[:maxi]
        for inp in words:
            if word.find(inp) != -1: # if word has inp do, returning != ==  True:
                tmp = word.replace(inp, "")

        word = word.replace(tmp,"")
        nwords.append(word)
        nwords = list(set(nwords))
        cutd = cutd+1

print nwords
print "\nWords Count: " + str(cw)
print "\nCutted Words Count: " + str(cutd)
print "\nFinal Words in list: " + str(len(nwords))
```

Comment: Difícil de entender qual é o objetivo do código. Tem como dar um exemplo de uma entrada e qual seria a saída esperada?

Comment: Realmente dificil de entender qual é o objetivo, tentei rodar esse codigo no python3, varios erros.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Como o Código deveria estar funcionando: Digamos que o input seja: **8** "cara" "vela" "abacaxi" "berta" A saída deveria ser: caravela, velacara, abacaxi, berta OU input: **5** "cara" "vela" "abacaxi" "berta" Saída: cara, vela, berta

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss A questão é que o ´itertools.product()´ faz todas as combinações possíveis entre strings, aí o que eu pensei foi em pegar essa essa string gerada pela função e verificar se ela encaixa no range que é a variável maxi, definida no input, se encaixa, vai pra lista ´nwords[]´, se não encaixa ela passa por um tratamento. Primeiro ela é cortada bem na posição definida pelo range com o ´word = word[:maxi]´, depois, e é isso que está dando erro, deve ser verificado nessa string se quando ela é cortada e sobra uma sílaba ou letra da string antes do tratamento

Comment: @Sidon o código foi escrito no 2.7, esqueci de avisar antes

Comment: @GMattos mas o `itertools.product` não retorna uma lista? Não entendi esse detalhe de sobrar sílaba.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Sim mas para cada palavra gerada pelo `itertools.product` e inserida na lista passa pelo `if len(word) <= maxi:` que verifica se a palavra gerada está dentro do limite, se estiver, passa sem tratamento, se não estiver, é onde mora o problema. Eu corto a string de acordo com o limite `word = word[:maxi]`, depois disso, dependendo da combinação, fica sobrando uma sílaba ou letra, a lógica seria verificar quais palavras completas existem nessa string cortada, apagar essas palavras até identificar o resto, apagar esse resto da string que vai de fato acabar na lista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui desenvolver o problema proposto, no meu git colocarei a versão completa e também continuarei trabalhando em seu melhoramento.

```
import sys, os
import itertools


def clnw(modelos, palavra):

    for a in modelos:

        palavra = palavra.replace(a, "")

    lx = palavra

    if lx != "":
        return lx 
    else: return "" 

def fixw(rst, plvr,total):
    if total == plvr.rfind(rst):
        return plvr
    else:
        st = plvr.rfind(rst)
        fn = len(plvr) -1

        plvrl = list(plvr)
        rstl = list(rst)

        while fn >= st:

            del plvrl[fn]

            fn = fn-1
        fix = ''.join(plvrl)

        return fix

maxi = sys.argv[1]

if int(maxi) > 24:
    print(">>For secure, the max of range of string was setup as 24<<")
    print("Old value: " + maxi)
    maxi = 24

maxi = int(maxi)

words = sys.argv[2:]
words.sort()
words.sort(key=len, reverse=True)

wn = len(words)
print(words)
print("Inserted Words: " + str(len(words)))
cw = 0
cutd = 0
nwords = []
tmp = ""
for word in map(''.join, itertools.permutations(words, r=wn)):
    cw = cw+1
    if len(word) <= maxi:
        nwords.append(word)
        nwords = list(set(nwords))

    else:
                #Permutations, slicing of the big ones

        word = word[:maxi]

        tmp = clnw(words, word)

        wn = wn-1


        word = fixw(tmp,word,maxi)
        nwords.append(word)
        nwords = list(set(nwords))


print(sorted(nwords))

temp = "temp.txt"

f = open(temp, "w")

for w in nwords:
    w = w.strip()
    f.write(w + '\n')

f.close()
```